# Grep (or maybe regex) check for pattern on lines before or after a match

Tags: regex, grep

I have a simple grep command that returns lines that match from a file.  Here's the problem:  Sometimes, when a line matches, I want to include the line before it.  What I want is a way to find all the lines that match a pattern, then use a different pattern to see if the line before each of those results match.

Let's say I want to get all lines containing 'bar', and the line before each of those only if they contain 'foo'.  Given an input like this:

```
    Spam spam eggs eggs
    Let's all go to the bar.
    Blah Blah Blah foo.
    Meh.
    foo foo foo
    Yippie, a bar.
```

I'd like a result like this:

```
    Let's all go to the bar
    foo foo foo
    Yippie, a bar.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `-B` option to include context lines before the match (there's also `-A` for including context lines after, and `-C` for including context lines before and after).  You can then pipe the result into another `grep`:

```
# Get all lines matching 'bar' and include one line of context before each match
# Then, keep only lines matching 'bar' or 'foo'
grep bar -B1 the-file | grep 'bar\|foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

don't have to use grep 2 times

```
awk '/bar/ && p~/foo/{
  print p
  print  
  next
}/bar/{print}{ p=$0}' file
```